# thousand separator php

Tags: php, string, number-formatting

I have this `$number = 100000.5;` pulled from the database. 
What i need is to format is as `100.000,5`

`str_replace` + `number_format` i figgured.

My replace works perfectly,

```
echo str_replace('.', ',', $row['anskaf_sum']);
```

(returns: 100000,5)
but when I add the number_format I fails somehow

```
number_format($row['anskaf_sum'] , 0, ',', '.');
```

returns

```
101
```

I have tried a few other things, but I do not seem to be able to get closer to the answer I need

thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure your $row['anskaf_sum'] does not hold some value you are not expecting?
Because:

```
<?php
        $number = 100000.5;
        echo number_format($number, 1, ",", ".");
?>
```

... this returns exactly what you want: 100.000,5

Comment: diddent see the small mistake of the 0 and the 1 :)

Comment: However even if it is 0 that still should not produce the 101 result you mentioned but 100.001  ;-). I answered your other question too, so you might check it out. Maybe it resolves some other issues you've been having.

Comment: Late response - but if he's already done the str_replace to inject commas into the number, then the number format script will definitely have issues resulting in other numbers when it tries to format malformed numbers. Just using number_format as mentioned here is more than enough.